# How to ignore pages that are not real webpages or contain msgbox with WebBrowser2?

Tags: c++, mshtml, iwebbrowser2

I used `System::Net::WebClient::DownloadString` to get HTML code of some webpages.
But, it doesn't work for some specific pages.

For this reason, I used WebBrowser2 for these pages.
However, this way has some problems since it really loads pages.

I want to do these:

1. if a page contains msgbox, I want to ignore it.
   (in this case, I don't want to see msg box and open other page. I don't need to get this page's HTML code.)
2. Some pages are not a webpage but file. If I open this, it calls download control.
   It really iritates me. I tried to filter urls that aren't webpages, but I failed.
   I want to Ignore pages that are not real webpage.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is generally handled by `DWebBrowserEvents2::NewWindow3`; you can cancel the new window. Only true for true popups, not HTML5 floating divs.

As for the downloading, that sounds like the URL identifies a resource which isn't of MIME type `text/html`. You'd have to get the header during `DWebBrowserEvents2::BeforeNavigate2`, and again you can cancel it.